# I'm having trouble understanding exactly what ASP is and how to upload an ASP website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

As of the start of this week I've been required to start learning how to develop websites in ASP. I have a moderate level of experience with C# through XNA, so that part of it isn't much trouble for me.

I've been following a [Music Store Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store) which takes me though setting up an "ASP.NET MVC 3" application.

I'm about done with the tutorial and have a functioning site when I run a test locally, but I don't understand what files need to be uploaded. I've worked on front-end updates for ASP websites before but they were completely different to this in terms of what files made up the site and so on.

I don't see a single `.aspx` page in my project which is what I assumed an ASP site was made of from experience. I'm starting to think that those projects weren't MVC projects but maybe just the "ASP.NET Web Application" style project.

Are ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC different? From what I vaguely understand, MVC is just a framework that wraps ASP.NET? Also, is *ASP* something or is that just a synonym for ASP.NET? Finally back to my initial confusion, what files are to be uploaded onto the server when I want to launch an ASP.NET MVC project?

Do I just upload this entire directory and the server will handle it in the same way that the inbuilt testing ASP server does? Or is the site compiled down into a couple of files somehow and I just upload one of these directories (I think I read that somewhere).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, when you say `ASP`, you're referring to old (obsolete) tech. ASP.NET is specifically what you're referring to in your question.

ASP.NET is a Microsoft technology which works cooperatively with the IIS server to provide a "Windows Application" type experience with web sites. Your web site logic is compiled in to a .NET DLL "Class Library." When a web request hits IIS with a URL matching your application directory, IIS starts up your application internally and maintains it.

> I don't understand what files need to be uploaded

Visual Studio actually has a built in publisher available for your use. See the `Build -> Publish` menu in VS / Web Developer.

> I don't see a single .aspx page in my project which is what I assumed an ASP site was made of from experience.

ASP.NET Web Forms uses the aspx extension for Pages, their frontend rendering component. On the other hand, ASP.NET MVC uses the concept of Views, which are not relient on a specific component. See the next paragraph.

> Are ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC different?

Yes. No. Maybe. ASP.NET contains all the "magic" which allows IIS - the web server - run the web application and serve up web pages. Volumes could (and have) been written on this. ASP.NET also supports much configuration through the means of Http Modules and Providers. These components are declared and configured through the web apps `web.config` file and are typically automagically created and persisted by IIS and ASP.NET. They collectively make up the glue that makes ASP.NET just *work* out of the box.

MVC was built on top of the existing foundation classes of ASP.NET. Some features have been loaned, a few have been replaced and more than a handful have been created in order to support the model-view-controller pattern.

For example, MVC gives us support for `View Engines` - a runtime library which allows us to write our Views (web pages) in a particular format. The ASPX View Engine existed during MVC's launch. Later came Razor, employing the `.cshtml` extension. Users of the MVC Framework have implemented a wide variety of their own view engines as well. This is possible due to the modular nature of ASP.NET and MVC.

> Do I just upload this entire directory and the server will handle it in the same way that the inbuilt testing ASP server does? Or is the site compiled down into a couple of files somehow and I just upload one of these directories (I think I read that somewhere).

I would recommend using the `Build -> Publish` menu in Visual Studio. You may use `web deploy` if your host supports it, but FTP and File System methods are available as well.

The `bin` folder contains the class libraries required to run your web application on the server. The `web.config` file provides the configuration to do so. However your Views are not compiled in to the assembly. They are published as-is and are rendered lazily by the view engine.

Answer (score 4):

ASP is an acronym for Active Server Pages.  Pre .NET, ASP was Microsoft's first iteration scripted web pages.  All of those pages typically ended with the extension .ASP.

When .NET was released, ASP was overhauled significantly and renamed ASP.NET.  The new version of ASP.NET attempted to model web development similar to windows application development, where you used controls and an event handling model.  That was Microsoft's primary model for web page development for many years, and it still around and supported, but today it is referred to as ASP.NET Web Forms.  ASP.NET Web Forms pages typically have the .ASPX extension you mentioned.

In the mid-2000s or so, Ruby on Rails took off, using an MVC based model for developing web applications.  A few years later, Microsoft released an alternate version of ASP.NET, called ASP.NET MVC, which used similar concepts.  Many people feel the MVC approach is a more natural method for developing web pages than the web forms model (note epic Q/A threads on this very site a few years ago).  In any case, ASP.NET MVC shares parts with ASP.NET Web Forms, but looks and works pretty differently; for one thing, there are no .ASPX pages as MVC, for the most part, uses a different form of routing to determine what to display.

That's a very brief history that glosses over a whole lot of subjects.  What you've posted a screenshot of, is an ASP.NET MVC project.

As far as publishing is concerned, the typical route for publishing an ASP.NET website is to open the project in Visual Studio, select Build|Publish, and tell VS where to put it.  Depending on what method you use, you may have to do additional configuration in IIS on the box where you published the site.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably familiar with ASP.NET WebForms, this is an MVC project. You can find more here:

[ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc)

In order to upload the site, you need to publish the website from inside Visual Studio to a local file location and then upload everything to the website.

If the target server doesn't have MVC installed, you can right click on the website project in Visual Studio and select "Add Deployable Dependencies".

This will ensure that the server has all the required files to run an MVC project.

Comment: +1 `This will ensure that the server has all the required files to run an MVC project` None of my providers are missing the Mvc assemblies, thankfully, but I wouldn't have known how to deploy it myself.